# Различающееся поведение go1.5beta2 на MacOS и Linux

Tags: linux, macos, golang, mac

Пример был взят из ["A Tour of Go"](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1)

Очевидно, что программа должна написать 10 строк: 5 строк "hello" и ещё 5 "world".

Однако, что мы имеем:

- Linux - 9 строк
- MacOS X - 10 строк

Вывод на Linux (9 строк):

```
$ go run 1.go 
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
world
hello
hello
```

Вывод на MacOS X (10 строк):

```
$ go run 1.go 
hello
world
world
hello
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
```

Может кто-нибудь объяснить, почему так выходит?

Linux `uname -a`:

```
Linux desktop 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MacOS X `uname -a`:

```
Darwin 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Thu Jul  9 22:56:16 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Исходный код из ссылки в начале:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    go say("world")
    say("hello")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем это я на ночь глядя запамятовал спеку :)

Развернутый ответ был дан на GitHub в официальном репозитории Go: [github issue #11848](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11848#issuecomment-124226261)

Суть проблемы была в том, что тест запускался на Linux-машине с более слабым CPU.